# How do I loop over all items in a DynamoDB table using boto?

Tags: python, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I'd like to query a DynamoDB table and retrieve all the items and loop over them using boto. How do I structure a query or scan that returns everything in the table?

Comment: looks like as of v2.1.1 boto doesn't support table scans. for now, changing my hash key to use a common value and using query to query on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preliminary support for the [Scan API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Scan.html) had been added to boto's layer2 for DynamoDB by Chris Moyer in [commit 522e0548](https://github.com/boto/boto/commit/522e054866899d6acf8b08d5ae8ff3e447e81c6e) (*Added scan to layer2 and Table*) and has meanwhile been updated by Mitch Garnaat in [commit adeb7151](https://github.com/boto/boto/commit/adeb715194a9d0e78d0e5f41638782c68c0071f8) (*Cleaned up the scan method on Layer2 and Table.*) to hide the layer1 details and enable intuitive querying - the respective [issue #574](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/574) is currently scheduled to be released with [boto 2.3](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues?sort=created&direction=desc&state=closed&page=1&milestone=6).

A usage sample is implicitly included via [tests/dynamodb/test_layer2.py](https://github.com/boto/boto/commit/adeb715194a9d0e78d0e5f41638782c68c0071f8#diff-2):

```
# Try scans
results = table.scan([('Tags', 'CONTAINS', 'table')])
n = 0
for item in results:
    n += 1
assert n == 2
```

Comment: This has been updated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664335/trouble-getting-a-dynamodb-scan-to-work-with-boto)