# Structure a dynamoDB table to enable ASC or DESC ordered pagination on * items in a table

Tags: nosql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to ORDER_BY by time/date, and paginate through all items in a table. [Scan](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Scan.html) seems designed to paginate through everything, but does not seem to have a "ASC/DESC" equiv. [Query](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Query.html) has *ScanIndexForward* but requires specific primary keys. (no way to SELECT * ?)

Based on the [first comment of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966105/how-do-i-loop-over-all-items-in-a-dynamodb-table-using-boto) I'm thinking the only way to achieve this is to use a common primary key (!?) and then Query based on that, focusing on the Range key. Is this really how it's supposed to work? I'd have to make a whole separate table with mirrored attributes if I wanted to Query an individual item based on a unique primary key.

Please excuse my NoSQL noobness. I'm a front-end dev who's only dabbled in MySQL and SimpleDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is what `Query` is for.  The hash key identifies the list of things to page over, and the range key indicates the position within the list.  If you can tolerate the latency hit, all you need to store in the table is primary keys where all the data being paged over lives, you can then issue a `BatchGetItem` to read a pageful of data in parallel.

Duplicate data isn't the sin in NoSQL that it is in the relational model, you're essentially crafting a MySQL style index by hand.