# Trouble getting a dynamodb scan to work with boto

Tags: boto, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using boto to access a dynamodb table.  Everything was going well until I tried to perform a scan operation.

I've tried a couple of syntaxes I've found after repeated searches of The Internet, but no luck:

```
def scanAssets(self, asset):
    results = self.table.scan({('asset', 'EQ', asset)})
         -or-
    results = self.table.scan(scan_filter={'asset':boto.dynamodb.condition.EQ(asset)})
```

The attribute I'm scanning for is called 'asset', and asset is a string.

The odd thing is the table.scan call always ends up going through this function:

```
def dynamize_scan_filter(self, scan_filter):
    """
    Convert a layer2 scan_filter parameter into the
    structure required by Layer1.
    """
    d = None
    if scan_filter:
        d = {}
        for attr_name in scan_filter:
            condition = scan_filter[attr_name]
            d[attr_name] = condition.to_dict()
    return d
```

I'm not a python expert, but I don't see how this would work.  I.e. what kind of structure would scan_filter have to be to get through this code?

Again, maybe I'm just calling it wrong.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Jim Baldwin, welcome to Stack Overflow. On this website [it's OK to answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). So instead of editing your question post, could you put the answer in an answer post and accept it (by ticking the checkmark at the left of your answer)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, looks like I had an import problem.  Simply using:

```
import boto
```

and specifying boto.dynamodb.condition doesn't cut it.  I had to add:

```
import dynamodb.condition
```

to get the condition type to get picked up.  My now working code is:

```
results = self.table.scan(scan_filter={'asset': dynamodb.condition.EQ(asset)})
```

Not that I completely understand why, but it's working for me now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this

```
exclusive_start_key = None
while True:
    result_set = self.table.scan(
        asset__eq=asset,  # The scan filter is explicitly given here
        max_page_size=100,  # Number of entries per page
        limit=100,
        # You can divide the table by n segments so that processing can be done parallelly and quickly.
        total_segments=number_of_segments,
        segment=segment,  # Specify which segment you want to process
        exclusive_start_key=exclusive_start_key  # To start for last key seen
    )
    dynamodb_items = map(lambda item: item, result_set)
    # Do something with your item, add it to a list for later processing when you come out of the while loop
    exclusive_start_key = result_set._last_key_seen
    if not exclusive_start_key:
         break
```

This is applicable for any field.

segmentation: suppose you have above script in test.py

you can run parallelly like

```
python test.py --segment=0 --total_segments=4
python test.py --segment=1 --total_segments=4
python test.py --segment=2 --total_segments=4
python test.py --segment=3 --total_segments=4
```

in different screens